# Stack ListView and PageView with DraggableScrollableSheet

Tags: flutter

I have the following use case: I have a map and want to have a set of cards that the user swipes left/right to see different venues on a map (when the user swipes the card, the map moves to that venue's location). And in each card, I want to be able to swipe up and see a list of events in that venue.

The problem is that having the cards of the venue prevents the user from interacting with the map directly (moving it, zooming, etc.).

So I created a minimal example to reproduce this problem: the ListView with the amber elements is the map. Then we have a PageView, which is what allows to swipe left/right between the cards, and a DraggableScrollableSheet with a ListView inside to swipe up the card and see the events of a venue (elements in red).

Here is the example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Scaffold(body: StackWidget()),
    );
  }
}

class StackWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const StackWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Stack(
      children: [
        ChildOne(),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: ChildTwo(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ChildOne extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChildOne({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 40,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.amber[((index + 1) * 100) % 900],
          child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${index + 1}')),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class ChildTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChildTwo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      itemCount: 4,
      controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.9),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return DraggableScrollableSheet(
          initialChildSize: 0.25,
          minChildSize: 0.25,
          maxChildSize: 0.9,
          snap: true,
          builder: (context, scrollController) {
            return Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.red[((index + 1) * 100) % 900],
                    child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${index + 1}')),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a dart pad: https://dartpad.dev/?id=df3e9edcd71afa9677a5d4938eb7e2cc

[image: example-image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few different ways to achieve the UI you want but for learning purposes I'll explain how to do it using your method.

The main reason why your map(list) will not move is because the widget does not get any pointer events, the events are blocked because the widgets on top `DraggableScrollableSheet` + `PageView` are taking all the space and thus consuming all the pointer events so we have to make sure that widget doesn't take the entire space or to at least send the event to widget behind it.

option one is easier so :

- turn off the automatic expansion of `DraggableScrollableSheet` by setting expand to false
- replace `PageView` with a `Row`
- add a horizontal `SingleChildScrollView` to allow scrolling
- change scrolling physics to `PageScrollPhysics` to keep the same behavior of a page view

updated code for ChildTwo:

```
class ChildTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChildTwo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      physics: const PageScrollPhysics(),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                initialChildSize: 0.25,
                minChildSize: 0.25,
                maxChildSize: 0.9,
                snap: true,
                expand: false,
                builder: (context, scrollController) {
                  return Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      controller: scrollController,
                      itemCount: 20,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(
                          height: 50,
                          color: Colors.red[((index + 1) * 100) % 900],
                          child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${index + 1}')),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Note**: this does not work on web for some reason.
Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Maybe because in web you need to scroll instead of dragging?

Comment: Right, I think the flutter web had the same scrolling behavior as other targets but it has changed, I don't know when but right now web is more like what you expect from a web app

Comment: @RaoufRahiche I'm accepting your answer because it does what it fixes my problem given the context I gave. However, I needed a solution in which I was able to take advantage of PageView's controller to programmatically change the page given a map location marker click. How could I achieve that?

Comment: You can use the scroll controller provided to a ListView the same way you use page controller, you don't have animateToPage in a scroll controller but because your widgets are fixed width you can scroll to page by scrolling to : pageNumber * width